# Reparametrization invariance in scalar QFT: What does it mean, exactly?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, sigma-models

In the Cecotti's book "Supersymmetric Field Theories" he wrote *" Physical quantities are independent of the fields we use to parametrize the configuration, that is, observables are invariant under field reparametrizations of the form  $\phi^i \rightarrow \varphi^i(\phi)$ "*

Can anyone explain to me what this means ? or, in other words, what is the principle to it he had referred ?

**Edit:** My question is: is this reparametrization invariance for all fields (e.g vector and spinor fields) or just for the scalar fields ?, is QFT a repametrization invariant theory? and can we consider the gauge invariance as a repametrization invariance? [I don't know also why one does not take this reparametrization invariance as a constraint, like the gauge invariance, which must reduce the number of degrees of freedom of the fields!!]

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the whole page, not just this sentence? I really don't know how to explain that differently.

It's analog to the general relativity. You can perform **coordinate** diffeomorphisms,
$$x^\mu\mapsto \tilde{x}^\alpha(x^\mu)$$
and they all get compensated by change of the **spacetime metrics** $g_{\mu\nu}$,
$$g_{\mu\nu}\mapsto \tilde{g}_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{\partial\tilde{x}^\mu}{\partial x^\alpha}g_{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial\tilde{x}^\nu}{\partial x^\beta}$$

Likewise here you can compensate arbitrary **field** diffeomorphism you wrote by change of the **target space** metrics $g_{ij}$ i.e. metrics of the manifold for which the fields $\phi^i$ serve as coordinates. Note that it's different from the spacetime metrics! So you have two metrics - one for spacetime and the different one for the target space.

So this principle is similar to the general covariance of the general relativity. As a matter of fact it is the general covariance in the string theory. There the physical spacetime arises as a target space for fields $X^A(\tau,\sigma)$ on the two-dimensional worldsheet.

Comment: Yes, I read the whole part and I think that your answer is his conclusion i.e the scalar field reparametrisation gives a transformation which can be viewed as a diffeomorphism and so the scalar fields can be viewed as coordinates on a manifold called the target space

Comment: As I mentioned in the question my problem is with the reparemetrizations and not with its consequences (I think that this is not due to the analogy with GR since this will imply that the scalar fields are coordinates and this is the conclusion !)

Comment: @Med Vall I can't get what you don't understand. Can you explain your question more clearly. This symmetry is a symmetry of the Lagrangian checked by direct computation. No analogy needed.

Comment: thanks for your answer and comments, Ok, I will edit it.

Comment: I updated my question.